# Why is my program printing 2 same lines in the last when I tried to rewrite some lines in an existing file on my computer?

Tags: c, file, if-statement, file-handling, eof

The background is the following: I search for an ID I want to replace and then I look at my file MedicalStore.txt for it. If I find it I replace it with another line of or record that didn't previously exist in the file. I make up another temporary file and copy-paste all the data with the exception of the searched ID which I replace using an If condition. I will attach the file as well.

```
            Modify(int SiD){
            struct customerinfo{
            char Prefix[20];
            char Name[20];
            int ID;
            unsigned long int Pnum;
            };
            struct customerinfo customer;
            FILE * Fptr;
            FILE * Ftemp;
    Fptr = fopen("MedicalStore.txt","r");
    Ftemp = fopen("replace.txt","w");
    char singleLine[150],newline[150],prefix[10],name[20];
    int id,c=0;
    unsigned long int num;
    while (!feof(Fptr)){
    fgets(singleLine,150,Fptr);
    c++;
    sscanf(singleLine,"%s %s %d %d\n",prefix,name,&id,&num);
    //printf("%s %s %d %d\n",prefix,name,id,num);
    if (id == SiD){
    strcpy(customer.Prefix,"Customer");
    printf("Enter Customer Name:\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(customer.Name);
    printf("Enter unique ID of Customer : ");
    scanf("%d",&customer.ID);
    printf("Enter phone number of customer : ");
    scanf("%d",&customer.Pnum);
    printf("%d",customer.Pnum);
    sprintf_s(newline,150, "%s %s %d %d\n",customer.Prefix,customer.Name,customer.ID,customer.Pnum);
    fputs(newline,Ftemp);
    } else {
    fputs(singleLine,Ftemp);
    }
    }
    fclose(Fptr);
    fclose(Ftemp);
    remove("MedicalStore.txt");
    rename("replace.txt","MedicalStore.txt");
    return 0;
    }
```

[Before editing with the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3WHL.png)
[I replaced the 2nd line with another record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQhlS.png)

Comment: Was the indentation lost in copy/paste, or your actual code looks like this?

Comment: The description for the removed function `gets` starts with: _**Never use this function**_. Read about why and you will never use it again.

Comment: You may want to read this: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/12149471)

Comment: @EugeneSh. I am new to the forum and I am kinda new to the programming world as well so please bear with my stupidity

Comment: @SyedMuhammadIsmail This is not about stupidity, but if your actual code really looks like this you will make yourself a huge favor by learning how to indent it properly.

Comment: I have tried to make the most out of my time by editing several source file for my project which is why some indentation would have lost/ignored by me. I am truly sorry for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the condition in the while loop

```
while (!feof(Fptr)){
fgets(singleLine,150,Fptr);
//...
```

The condition can occur only after the following call of `fgets`. So if `fgets` encountered EOF the value of the string  `singleLine` was not changed, It keeps the previous entered data. As a result the last line of the file is processed two times.

Instead you need to write

```
while ( fgets(singleLine,150,Fptr) != NULL ) {
//...
```

Pay attention to that this call

```
 fflush(stdin);
```

has undefined behavior.

Also the function `gets` is unsafe and is not supported by the C Standard.

Comment: I couldnt continue with the processing without fflush(stdin) because my gets functions was not working. Also got to know from you guys that gets function is unsafe. I will try to not use it from now on and will spread the word as well